# Expected MIME-type to be ‘application/javascript’ or ‘text/JavaScript’ , but got null

Tags: xcode, react-native, react-native-ios

I have been trying to run my React Native (ios) project on my physical phone. After it has finished building and bundling, it will give this expected MIME type error. How do I solve this? Thank you!!

Comment: Can you share some build logs?

Comment: @minchaej 
Hi, here are the logs where the error occurs. It only occurs after the build has succeeded. 

[native] Expected MIME-Type to be 'application/javascript' or 'text/javascript', but got '(null)'.

[native] Invalidating <RCTCxxBridge: 0x109b0f820> (parent: <RCTBridge: 0x2813a4070>, executor: RCTWebSocketExecutor)

[native] Module ViewController requires main queue setup since it overrides `init` but doesn't implement `requiresMainQueueSetup`. In a future release React Native will default to initializing all native modules on a background thread unless explicitly opted-out of.

Comment: @minchaej There is also this error 
Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
    at Object.readSync (node:fs:720:3)
    at tryReadSync (node:fs:430:20)
    at Object.readFileSync (node:fs:476:19)
    at UnableToResolveError.buildCodeFrameMessage